# Django | Triggering a function from list in template

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to make a facebook like Newsfeed.
I have a `Post` which contains all post. After sending it from the view I load the posts to the templates with `{% for p in posts %}`, for each post I add 2 buttons (share, like) and an input (comment).

How can I know which of them was clicked so I can send the post.id back to the view, including the name, and value and trigger a function to handle them in the database?

I want to know after I click an input what was it, what it included and for which post it belongs.

Comment: ok! really simple ! you must add distinct attribute name value: e.g: <button type="something" name="share"></button> now in your view you make test like this:>>>> if "share" in request.POST: do something.... ?

Comment: but if i just know the name i cant know for which 'Post' the button belongs

Comment: request.POST is a dict. This dict have many items. all name of your fields have name attribute are referenced on request.POST !

Comment: Trys to do something like :>>>> print('---->>>>', request.POST) in your view when submit and see !

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I would have approached this is something as follows:

I would have specific views to handle share and like functionalities, I would rather have them as two separate views. For them you then create urls, definitely you will be also providing post identifier as a parameter to this url.

For eg:

```
class LikePost(View):
    def post(self, request, post_id, *args, **kwargs):
        code
```

For this class, you can then have a url like `^/post/(?P<post_id>\d+)/$`.

Now for more simplicity in your Post model class you can write a model method that returns you the url for LikePost view for an instance of post.

Something like this:

```
def like_post_url(self):
     return reverse('appname:reversename-for-url', args=(self.id,))
```

So now when you loop posts in template you can simply assign this url as value for href in anchor tag you use for button. So every button will have its own url for share, like and also for input.

I think this should make it clear on how you can proceed with simplicity.